# Return the subset of a list with the largest sum up to n recursively

Tags: python, recursion

```
def pack(L, n):
    '''Return the subset of L with the largest sum up to n
    >>> s = [4,1,3,5]
    >>> pack(s, 7)
    {3, 4}
    >>> pack(s, 6)
    {1, 5}
    >>> pack(s, 11)
    {1, 4, 5}
    '''
```

I'm asked to code this. It takes in a list and an integer and returns the best combination to get that integer less than or equal to.

I used a helper function that takes in the sum, but it's not correct since I don't know how I could replace a number while in recursion.

```
# doesn't work as intended
def pack_helper(L, n, sum=0):
    '''Return the subset of L with the largest sum up to n and the sum total
    >>> s = [4,1,3,5]
    >>> pack_helper(s, 7)
    ({3, 4}, 7)
    >>> pack(s, 6)
    ({1, 5}, 6)
    >>> pack(s, 11)
    ({1, 4, 5}, 10)
    '''
    package = set()
    if L == []:
        result = (package, sum)
    else:
        first = L[0]
        (package, sum) = pack_helper(L[1:], n, sum)
        if sum < n and (first + sum) <= n:
            package.add(first)
            sum = sum + first

    return (package, sum)
```

Any hints or help? Thx

Comment: Does the list have repeating numbers?

Comment: None of the examples have them though its not stated in the question, so i'd assume yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple recursive function that does the job:

```
def pack(L, n):
    '''Return the subset of L with the largest sum up to n
    >>> s = [4,1,3,5]
    >>> pack(s, 7)
    {3, 4}
    >>> pack(s, 6)
    {1, 5}
    >>> pack(s, 11)
    {1, 4, 5}
    '''

    if all(j > n for j in L):
        return set()

    return max(({j} | pack(L[i+1:], n-j) for i, j in enumerate(L) if j <= n), key=sum)
```

If you're using Python 3, you can pass the `default` parameter to `max` instead:

```
def pack(L, n):
    return max(({j} | pack(L[i+1:], n-j) for i, j in enumerate(L) if j <= n), key=sum, default=set())
```

Answer (score 0):

The test data here is small enough that brute force is pretty fast. Recursion is not necessary:

```
from itertools import chain, combinations

# taken from the itertools documentation
def powerset(iterable):
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))

def pack(L, n):
    best_set, best_sum = (), 0
    for candidate in powerset(L):
        total = sum(candidate)
        if best_sum < total <= n:
            best_set, best_sum = candidate, total
    return best_set
```

However, assuming positive weights, the [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) solution is pretty short.

```
def pack(L, n):
    assert all(w > 0 for w in L), 'weights must all be positive'
    a = [((), 0)] * (n + 1)
    for w in L:
        a = [ (a[x - w][0] + (w,), a[x - w][1] + w)
                if w <= x and a[x][1] < a[x - w][1] + w
                else a[x] for x in range(n + 1) ]
    return a[n][0]
```

How does this work?

`a[x]` stores the best set of weights processed so far that sum up to `x` or less (and the sum, just to save time). Before any weights have been processed, these are all empty `()`.

To process a new weight `w` at target `x`, one of the following two sets must be the best.

- the best set of weights without this new weight that sum up to `x` (the old `a[x]`), or
- the best set of weights without this new weight that sum up to `x - w`, plus this new weight `w`

Once all the weights are processed, the solution is right there at the end.

---

By the way, this is the well-known [0/1 knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem). (The Wikipedia article currently has a solution that uses O(len(L) * n) time and O(len(L) * n) space, but it's doable in O(n) space, as I demonstrated here.)